# Display ACF object field data using Elementor Custom Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, query-posts

Hello i'm working on a website using elementor pro + ACF.
I have create a custom post type (CPT1) with ACF object field that take another CPT2 as values. I would like to display on my CPT1 page all CPT2 linked. How can I used Custom Query to display this?
I tried to write this but still not working

```
add_action('elementor/query/13600', function ($query) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'CPT1');
    $results_posts= get_field('cpt1_field_for_cpt2',$post_id,false);
    $meta_query[] = [
         'post_in' => $results_posts->ID ,
    ];
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
});
```

Comment: Where did `$post_id` come from? I don't see it being passed to the function in any way, check that to see if it contains what you expect, probably not.

Comment: Problem solves with this code  :

```function my_cpt_query( $query ) {
    $myPostObjetField= get_field('cpt1_field_for_cpt2',$post_id,false);
 foreach( $myPostObjetField as $post_field_item_value ) {
   $ids[] = (int) $post_field_item_value;
    }
 $query->set( 'post_type', 'CPT2');
    $query->set( 'post__in', $ids);
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/13600', 'my_cpt_query' );```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be solved with this code  :

```
function my_cpt_query( $query ) {
    $myPostObjetField= get_field('cpt1_field_for_cpt2',$post_id,false);
    foreach( $myPostObjetField as $post_field_item_value ) {
            $ids[] = (int) $post_field_item_value;
    }
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'CPT2');
    $query->set( 'post__in', $ids);
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/13600', 'my_cpt_query' );
```